# Replacing header in data frame based on values in second data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
df.A

  A B C
x 1 3 4
y 5 4 6
z 8 9 1
```

And I want to replace the column names in the first based on column values in a second:

```
 df.B

 Low High
 A   D
 B   F
 C   G
```

Such that I get:

```
df.A
  D F G
x 1 3 4
y 5 4 6
z 8 9 1
```

How would I do it?

I have tried extracting the vector `df.B$High` from `df.B` and using this in `names(df.A)`, but everything is in alphabetical order and shifted over one. Furthermore, this only works if the order of columns in `df.A` is conserved with respect to the elements in `df.B$High`, which is not always the case (and in my real example there is no numeric or alphabetical way to sort the two to the same order). So I think I need an `rbind`-type argument for matching elements, but I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! I chose @joran 's because I think it is the most generalizable for my needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rename` from **plyr**:

```
library(plyr)
dat <- read.table(text = "  A B C
 x 1 3 4
 y 5 4 6
 z 8 9 1",header = TRUE,sep = "")
> new <- read.table(text = "Low High
  A   D
  B   F
  C   G",header = TRUE,sep = "")
> rename(dat,replace = setNames(new$High,new$Low))
  D F G
x 1 3 4
y 5 4 6
z 8 9 1
```

Answer (score 1):

using `match`:

```
df.A <- read.table(sep=" ", header=T, text="
A B C
x 1 3 4
y 5 4 6
z 8 9 1")
df.B <- read.table(sep=" ", header=T, text="
Low High
A D
B F
C G")

df.C <- df.A
names(df.C) <- df.B$High[match(names(df.A), df.B$Low)]
df.C
#   D F G
# x 1 3 4
# y 5 4 6
# z 8 9 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can play games with the row names of `df.B` to make a lookup more convenient:

```
rownames(df.B) <- df.B$Low
names(df.A) <- df.B[names(df.A),"High"]

df.A
##   D F G
## x 1 3 4
## y 5 4 6
## z 8 9 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach abusing `factor`:

```
f <- factor(names(df.A), levels=df.B$Low)
levels(f) <- df.B$High
f
## [1] D F G
## Levels: D F G

names(df.A) <- f

## Desired results
```